# Which years were "not good" for the Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who

In the *Doctor Who* episode "Deep Breath", season 8 episode 1, after the Doctor regenerates (12<sup>th</sup>, Peter Capaldi), he  says to Clara:

> I'm the Doctor. I've lived for over two thousand years, and not all of them were good. I've made many mistakes, and it's about time that I did something about that.

Does he mean the "dangerous things" he did in incarnations 1-12? What were the mistakes specifically? And what years did the Doctor think were not good?

Comment: @user63250 I've tried to fix the grammar, punctuation, and capitalization of your question. You should consider splitting your question into two, since it's really two separate questions: a) what mistakes, b) what years were bad.  This site is most effective when individual questions are asked separately.

Comment: i think you'll have a better chance at good answers if you separate your two question into two separate postings (click the 'ask a question' button again.) Oh and welcome to the site!

Comment: thanks but how do i seperate it it looks fine

Comment: @user63250 Start by capitalizing your I's.

Answer (score 2):

Since the 2005 reboot, The Doctor has made it clear that he loathes himself. He doesn't like endings, and he doesn't like to look back because of guilt. We can go back to the Dream Lord in season's 5 "Amy's choice" and also this scene from Series 6 "Let's Kill Hitler", right after River Song poisons him:

> DOCTOR: I'm shutting down. I need an interface. Voice interface. Come on, emergency.
>
> HOLO-DOCTOR: Voice interface enabled.
>
> DOCTOR: Oh no, no, no, no, no. Give me someone I like.
>
> (Holo-Rose Tyler appears)
>
> DOCTOR: Oh, thanks. Give me guilt.
>
> (Holo-Martha Jones appears)
>
> DOCTOR: Also guilt.
>
> (Holo-Donna Noble appears)
>
> DOCTOR: More guilt. Argh. Come on, there must be someone left in the universe I haven't screwed up yet.
>
> (Holo-Nine-year old Amelia Pond, from back in "The Eleventh Hour")
>
> HOLO-AMELIA: Voice interface enabled.
>
> DOCTOR: Oh. Oh, Amelia Pond, before I got it all wrong. My sweet little Amelia.

I guess the mistakes he refers to mean how he has "screwed up" the lives of his past companions, which is ironic, because in the end

> The exact same thing, if not worse, happened to Clara at the end of season 9

Comment: why was it hes companions was it the "dangerous things" he did in incarnations 1-12?